# Получить адрес возврата после выполнения процедуры

Tags: ассемблер, стек

Есть такой код на MASM32:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
ExitProcess proto: DWORD

.code
    start:
        push DWORD PTR 2
        push DWORD PTR 3
        call AddDigs
        mov ecx, [esp - 4];

        invoke ExitProcess, 0

        AddDigs proc
            mov eax, [esp + 8]
            add eax, [esp + 4]
            ret 8
        AddDigs endp
    end start
```

Я хочу разобраться, что происходит со стеком при вызове этой процедуры и хочу получить адрес возврата, который хранился в стеке.

Сначала мы кладем на стек 2, регистр ESP явно указывает на это число. Затем кладем туда число 3, оно ложится на вершину, и теперь двойка находится по адресу [esp - 4]. После выполнения инструкции call на стек помещается адрес возврата 0040100F, а числа 2 и 3 находятся теперь по адресам [esp - 8] и [esp - 4] соответственно. Будем считать, что в процедуре вместо ret 8 написано ret, т.е. мы просто снимаем со стека адрес возврата и переходим в отладчике на следующую строчку после call, а мусор остается в стеке. Как в этом месте получить значение адреса возврата?

Если сразу после вызова call выполнить инструкцию mov ecx, [esp - 4], то в регистре ecx окажется число 2, а инструкция mov ecx, [esp - 8] помещает туда число 3. Почему так? Ведь двойка находится дальше от вершины стека, чем тройка, и поэтому чтобы добраться до нее, надо отнять от вершины стека не 4, а 8.

Когда мы снимаем со стека адрес возврата, регистр esp увеличивается на 4, потому что стек растет в сторону уменьшения адресов. Значит, чтобы добраться до адреса возврата, который только что лежал на вершине, от адреса вершины надо отнять 4. Почему же вместо адреса возврата оттуда вытаскиваются числа?

[image: Олли дебагер]

На второй картинке программа, где в процедуре вместо ret 8 написано просто ret. В окне стека видно, как в сторону увеличения адресов лежат последовательно числа 3 и 2. То есть адрес возврата находится выше и не виден в этом окне? Кажется, получить его обратно все-таки удалось, но все равно расскажите побольше теории обо всем этом.

[image: Олли2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим изменение состояния стека по шагам.

Пусть начальное значение esp == X. Состояние стека перед вызовом функции (текущее значение esp указываем стрелочкой):

```
-> X: YYYYYYYY ; в вершине стека что-то лежит, не важно что.
```

После команды `push DWORD PTR 2` esp уменьшается на 4, по новому адресу, лежащему в esp, записывается 2:

```
-> X-4: 2
   X-0: YYYYYYYY
```

После команды `push DWORD PTR 3` esp снова уменьшается на 4, по адресу в esp записывается 3:

```
-> X-8: 3
   X-4: 2
   X-0: YYYYYYYY
```

После вызова `call AddDigs` esp уменьшается на 4, по адресу esp кладется адрес возврата:

```
-> X-0Ch: RETADDR
   X-08h: 3
   X-04h: 2
   X-00h: YYYYYYYY
```

При выходе из процедуры по команде `ret 8` из стека извлекается адрес возврата, esp увеличивается на на 4, после этого esp увеличивается на значение операнда ret (на 8):

```
   X-0Ch: RETADDR
   X-08h: 3
   X-04h: 2
-> X-00h: YYYYYYYY
```

Таким образом получается, что по адресу esp-4 лежит 2, по адресу esp-8 лежит 3, по адресу esp-0Ch (esp-12) - адрес возврата.

Comment: А что будет, если перед выполнением ret положить на стек какой-то другой адрес? Подмена адреса возврата и выполнение произвольного участка кода?

Comment: @typemoon, да, именно так. Но проще не добавлять что-то, а изменить уже лежащий там адрес возврата.